# MonoTouch.Dialog: AccessoryViews

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, uitableview

I need to put a check beside a certain row, but when using this override of course I get the below warning. Where in MonoTouch.Dialog do I then enable a check?

```
public override UITableViewCellAccessory AccessoryForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{       
  return UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark; (For a row of course, simplified here)
}
```

**WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in   Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is deprecated, and instead if you need to use this, you need to configure your UITableViewCells accordingly by setting the AccessoryType and AccessoryView properties on it.

Just create a new Element class that implements the behavior you need, check my recent blog on patterns for building Elements:

http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html

Comment: As always, thank you for your support of the Monotouch community.